# Matlab error with vertcat and cell arrays

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I'm trying to concatenate two arrays as follows:

```
z={ '35' {'test'} ; '45' {'test'}}
z={z{:} ;{'55' {'test'}}}
```

I would expect the result to be

```
 {35 {'test'}
 45  {'test'}
 55 {'test'}}
```

but instead I get:

Error using vertcat

Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

What am I forgetting? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want numbers or numstrings, i.e. `35` or `'35'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by `z{:}` which lists all *content* of `z` 'into' a `N by 1` vector and when you try to collect all the elements with the outer `{}` it throws the error due to mismatching dimensions.

You might be using too many `{ }` and you can concatenate cell arrays with `[ ]`:

```
z = { '35' 'test'
     '45'  'test'};
z = [z; {'55' 'test'}]
```

The command window will display:

```
z = 
    '35'    'test'
    '45'    'test'
    '55'    'test'
```

Comment: Sorry, I'd like the second element to be a nested cell array if possible. Is it still possible to cat them? Never mind, figured it out: 

z={ '35' {'test'} ; '45' {'test'}};
z=[z;{'55' {'derp'}};

Thanks!